# Lubuntu 14.04 cannot try Lubuntu without installing-error messages

Tags: system-installation, kernel, lubuntu

I have Lubuntu 13.10 installed. Works great. I downloaded Lubuntu 14.04 and burned to disc.

To test I tried the option to try Lubuntu without installing.

I got several error messages which I did not understand.

The first error message contained the following:

"Kernel Panic-not syncing"

There were other error messages that followed plus a lot of codes.

Then the last error message contained the following:

"drm_kms_helper: panic occurred  switching back to text console"

I had to cold reboot. Nothing worked. Computer completely froze including t

he keyboard, mouse and I could not even eject the disc until the cold reboot.

This did not happen with 13.10 which installed smoothly with no problems 6 months ago.

Sounds to me like a kernel problem although I would think it would work just to try Lubuntu without installing. I remember trying a pre-release Kubuntu 14.04 and I was able to try it without installing just fine.

Is there a fix or should I attempt to download the image again and re-burn to disc.

Please advise if possible. I was very suprised it did not work considering Lubuntu 13.10 and a pre-release Kubuntu 14.04 worked.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I should add that I tried the 14.04 disc on another computer that has a completely different configuration and received the exact same error messages as posted.

Answer (score 0):

After you downloaded Lubuntu 14.04 did you perform an MD5Sum?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
The hashes have to match and perhaps yours don't.  If they do not, download the ISO again.

Comment: I did download the ISO again and I did finally get to try Lubuntu before installing on one of the computers but I haven't tried on the other. I did check the MD5Sum on the new download and it did match. I will try the other computer on Monday. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I got it the ISO to work! However I am having difficulty with accessing the "Properties" option of any Start Menu Program entry and I still cannot blacklist Bluetooth and IVP6. Every time I attempt to access the "Properties" nothing happens and my entire Start Menu freezes. I did a complete update and now the "Properties" option is no longer available. I have given up on blacklisting Bluetooth and IVP6.

Comment: Have you installed Lubuntu 14.04 or are you still trying it?

Comment: Yes I have Lubuntu 14.04 installed with all current updates. The "Properties" option is completely missing from all Start Menu Program entries. Is there any way to get that option back and working when you right click on it?